# angular controller doesn't run after page back

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple angular controller that should http-get a json and populate a view every 10 seconds hence:

```
function getNews($scope,$interval,$http)
{
     $scope.init=getNews;
     tick($http,$scope);
     $interval(function(){tick($http,$scope)},10000);
}


function tick($http,$scope)
{            
     $http.get(url).
     success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
     {
          $scope.listView=(data);            
     })
}
```

my problem is that after opening an external link and then hitting "back" the controller stops running
p.s. I don't use no routing. it's a realy simple app

thanks

Comment: Honestly, its difficult to even see what is going on here. Please checkout this link: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide.

And why not just use something like socket.io for updating the view as needed rather than making unnecessary http requests?

Comment: thanks for referring the styleguide, but it's only 15 loc.
I certainly will use socket.io or websockets if I could make them work with phonegap (which is my final destination)